# How can i add Custom Print button on Managed products Grids and print those details?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, products, print

I need to print my products details like name, SKU, price, image.

**Code :**

```
<?php  
set_time_limit(0);
//THIS SCRIPT JUST INITIALS THE PROFILE TO BE RUN VIA MAGENTO ADMIN "RUN PROFILE IN POPUP". Its the same thing as click just via this file that you can run via Cron
$profileId = 1; // SYSTEM - IMPORT/EXPORT - DATAFLOW PROFILES PROFILES <-- you need to go into your Magento admin and grab the exact profile ID

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$sku = 10; //this sku you get it from your text box.
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku', 'price', 'thumbnail'))
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $sku));

$imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');
foreach($_product as $prod){
    $name      = $prod->getName();
    $price     = $prod->getPrice();
    $thumbnail = $imageHelper->init($prod, 'thumbnail')->resize(150,220);

}

  echo "Name:   ", $name;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Sku:    ", $sku;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Price:  ", $price; 
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<img src='".$thumbnail ."'>";   
?>
```

Everything Okay..

How can I add this to managed products grid, like if I click print, the above details should get them printed?

Comment: This code works for me https://pastebin.com/2iaJgfra To search apart from by sku, by EAN code How can I do it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143224)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will print the grid window.

> Navigate to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml

If there is no **local.xml** then creates it.

and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout>
   <adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
        <reference name="products_list">
            <action method="addButton">
                <id>my_button_identifier</id>
                <data>
                    <label>Print Grid</label>
                    <class>some-class</class>
                    <onclick>printgrid()</onclick>
                </data>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="my_button_url" template="my_module/printdata.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
</layout>
```

Now navigate to

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/my_module/printdata.phtml

and add below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function printgrid(){
        window.print();
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: i have 2 doubts first one,, what i need here " <class>some-class</class>"

Comment: and where i can paste my custom code for print...  "<block type="adminhtml/template" name="my_button_url" template="my_module/printdata.phtml" />"

Comment: You can add your class name anything that you want. And which code you are talking about? In my answer, there are only two files. **local.xml** for showing print button and **printdata.phtml** for printing the current window.

Comment: I have added app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml   sourcecode: https://codepaste.net/6dtdi1  and app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/my_module/printdata.phtml   source code: https://codepaste.net/hxdtrf

Comment: may i know what is the error?